# Does Microsoft still release most Windows fixes on the second Tuesday of the month?

Tags: windows, security, windows-update

For a long time, Microsoft had a tradition to have a Patch Tuesday on the second Tuesday of the month where they release fixes and fix rollups for Windows, Office and other Microsoft software. However, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_Tuesday):

> At the Ignite 2015 event, Microsoft revealed a change in distributing security patches. They release security updates to home PCs, tablets and phones as soon as they are ready, while enterprise customers will stay on the monthly update cycle, which was reworked as Windows Update for Business.

This only mentions security patches. Should I conclude from this snippet that the non-security updates are still released on the traditional Patch Tuesday?

Comment: Yes;  Patch Tuesday still happens

Answer (score 0):

[On 2nd Tuesday Microsoft will release now a preview update](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/windowsitpro/2016/10/07/more-on-windows-7-and-windows-8-1-servicing-changes/) that will be released the upcoming month as part of the security monthly quality rollup.

> **A preview of the monthly quality rollup**
>
> - **An additional monthly rollup containing a preview of new non-security
>     fixes that will be included in the next monthly rollup, as well as
>     fixes from all previous monthly rollup**.  This can also be called the
>     “preview rollup.”
> - **This preview rollup will be released on the third
>     Tuesday of the month (also referred to as the “C week”).**
> - This will be published to WSUS using the “Updates” classification as an optional update.  It will also be available via Windows Update (where all
>     consumer PCs will install it) and on the Windows Update Catalog. With
>     WSUS, you can enable support for “express installation files” to
>     ensure that client PCs only download the pieces of a particular
>     monthly rollup that they haven’t already installed, to minimize the
>     network impact. Starting in early 2017 and continuing for several
>     months, older fixes will also be added to the preview rollup, so it
>     will eventually become fully cumulative; installing the latest monthly
>     rollup will then get your PC completely up to date.

So install the Quality Rollup and not only the "Security Only" Rollup at patchday and you're fine.